# why are there rounding errors if I assign a datatype long to a datatype float?

Tags: java, types, rounding, precision

the question from my teacher is:
Write down assignments who are possible but where rounding errors could occur.
This is in Java.

```
float f;
long l;
double d;

f = l;
d = l;
```

That is the answer but why? The value and maximum value of float is higher and float is a floating number. in contrast long are just full numbers so why are there rounding errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floating point numbers become less accurate in absolute terms as they get bigger. Beyond a certain point, the difference between the closest two exactly-representable floating point numbers is more than 1.

Or to look at it the other way round, look at the closest `float` representation to `Long.MAX_VALUE`. Now look at the closest `float` representation to `Long.MAX_VALUE - 1`...

Aside from anything else, you should be able to work out that not every `long` is representable as a `float` just by the size of the datatypes: there are 2<sup>32</sup> possible bit patterns for `float` (not all of which are normal numbers) and 2<sup>64</sup> possible bit patterns for `long`.

Comment: I tried to do what you said but I get the same value for:

f = Long.MAX_VALUE;

System.out.println(f);

and

f = Long.MAX_VALUE -1;

System.out.println(f);

Comment: @sceiler: Right - now think about why that's the case.

Answer (score -1):

Reason : float 32 bit, long is 64 bit  in java

Comment: That's not enough detail IMO - because the same is *also* true for `double`, and could easily be true for an 80-bit floating point type.